# Using Powerpoint Shape object in Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am writing this VBA code in Excel which makes changes in a powerpoint file. Everything is working fine except the below.
When I call the FormatICTable function, I get a runtime error i.e."Type mismatch". It looks like to me that shape object which I am passing as the first argument is creating the problem. Any suggestions ?

```
Sub controlPPT()
    Dim PPT As Object
    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Dim pres As Presentation
    With Application.FileDialog(1)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "PPT files", "*.pptx"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            PPT.Presentations.Open .SelectedItems(1)

            Dim sld As Slide

            Set pres = PPT.ActivePresentation
            For Each sld In pres.Slides
                sld.Select
                If sld.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Internal comparison" Then
                    Call FormatICTable(sld.Shapes(2), sld)
                End If
            Next

            pres.Save
            Set pres = Nothing
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Function FormatICTable(shp As Shape, sld As Slide)
    'My code here
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got the answer myself
Shape object should be decalred as PowerPoint.Shape in function signature instead of using only Shape class.

```
Function FormatICTable(shp As PowerPoint.Shape, sld As Slide)
    'My code here
End Function
```

Comment: @Steve, why is it so, I have realized that sometimes, not selecting the slide may stop the macro from running properly while working with objects on that page.